# Possibilities of Flex Mobile on Symbian OS

Tags: apache-flex, air, symbian

recently ive been doing research and testing of Flex Mobile framework for iOS and Android platforms, to see some good results.

I could not, however, find enough information (that are not outdated) about Flex Mobile on Symbian OS.

Is it possible, to package Flex mobile application (built in Flash Builder 4.6) also for Symbian OS? Flash builder only offers iOS, Android and Blackberry platform packaging.

Does Symbian OS support AIR3 platform? - from what i understand, only Flash Lite is supported. 
Is Flash Lite capable of rendering Flex Mobile apps?

Any link to valuable resource covering my questions will be **appreciated**.

Thanx for your help

Comment: No; Flex (or more accurately AIR) is not supported and since Nokia is migrating from Symbian to Windows Phone, it is unlikely to ever be supported. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian_OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Flash Lite and full-fledged AS3 (Flex Spark mobile) are not near anyhow.

I don't think it would be easy or even possible for a Flex kind of apps (since devices running Symbian are usually not that powerful compared to iOS or Android devices). But here's something you could using Google:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_port_Adobe_AIR_to_WRT
http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2010/03/03/helisso-a-packager-for-symbian-devices/